# Spring Boot: How to get the Serialized Name from FieldError.getField()

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, serialization, deserialization

Is there a way getting the serialized name in an `ExceptionHandler` that catches `MethodArgumentNotValidExceptions` with the `FieldError.getField()` method?

(see also https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html#getField--)

I have my POJO with the entry

```
@NotNull
@JsonProperty("photo-urls")
private List<URL> photoUrls;
```

and this code in the `ExceptionHandler`:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
private static Error handleException(final MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, final HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
final List<ObjectError> exceptionErrors = ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors();

exceptionErrors.forEach((final ObjectError exceptionError) -> {
    if (exceptionError instanceof FieldError) {
        final FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) exceptionError;
        final InvalidParam invalidParam = new InvalidParam();

        invalidParam.setName(fieldError.getField());
...
```

and whenever this field is missing (violating the `@NotNull` constraint), `getField()` returns `photoUrls` instead of `photo-urls`. But the for client `photo-urls` would be the right name.

My configuration seems fine, the client uses `photo-urls` and it works as long as no Exception is thrown.

Comment: No. As the validation is done based on the properties of the object NOT on how those are entered on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum. What would be a "nice" solution therefore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring developers take care:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25105